# Kotlin : App is getting crashed after enabled proguard

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard

I have written this model class to get configurations from Firbase database

```
    @Keep
    class Configuration {

        @SerializedName("BASE_API_URL")
         var BASE_API_URL: String = ""

        @SerializedName("BASE_URL")
        var BASE_URL: String = ""
    }
```

I Am Getting the following error. after proguard is enabled

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: base_api_url
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$a.a()
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$a.<init>(:5)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.a()
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.a(:4)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(:1)
    at com.io.chefjoy.customer.ui.activity.SplashScreenActivity$fetchConfigData$masterVEL$1.onDataChange()
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent()
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire()
    at a.d.b.d.d.c.b.run(:4)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Comment: Show your method ?

Answer (score 0):

Does your `gradle` proguard line looks like this ?

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

Also problem might be in `@Keep` since your `@SerializedName` and variable name are the same. So try removing `@Keep` or keep `@Keep` annotation and instead rename your variables to lowercase ones and see if it'll work.

Comment: i made that changes . i am getting null pointer exception on Firebase method onDataChange()

Comment: Try changing types to Nullable String?

Comment: Change But did not work. Actually am getting the data from Firebase , am serializing it  and saving in shared Preference. when i enable proguard. then it crashes and error is nullpointerException